# guessing the precision of each of my solutions using fsolve (scipy)

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I want to know the error (or uncertainty) of each of my solutions in a system of equations when I'm using `scipy.optimize.fsolve` from. For example (from the documentation):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(x):
    return [x[0] * np.cos(x[1]) - 4,
            x[1] * x[0] - x[1] - 5]

root, infodict, ier, msg = fsolve(func, [1, 1], full_outupt=1)
```

I want to know the precision of `root[0]` and `root[1]`, not how good the method was (that is the value of `r`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you interpret 'precision' in this case you might have to adapt the answer (square instead of abs to get mean squared error, etc)

The absolute error induced by the difference between calculated and the exact solution is by definition given by

```
np.abs(func(root))
```

since you expect the result to be 0 in the optimal case and thus

```
np.abs(func(x_true)-func(root)) = np.abs(func(root))
```

If you - however - want to know the difference between `x_true` and `root`: You can generally not expect to know that, otherwise you would already know the answer and wouldn't have to use an iterative algorithm to approximate the solution. You can only limit the acceptable error using `fsolve(xtol=...)`.

This is the very nature of algorithmically vs algebraically solving an equation or am i missing the point here?

If you would like to solve algebraically have a look at `SymPy` and its [solver](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).

Comment: That's not true as I know from numerical methods. In a bisection method, the width of your step will be your precision. But here, because is an hybrid method, and I get many outputs, I don't know which is the measure  of precision and which output it is. From the documentation I know some of them (Jacobian, fvec...), but things like qtr I don't know exactly what it is.